# Aurelia - Show/Hide element based on select option

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How do I hide the div class if the **value** chosen in the select option is **usd** ?

**app.html**

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control" value.bind=""> 
      <option repeat.for="option of Options" model.bind="option.value">
           ${option.name} 
      </option>
</select>

<div class="row">
  <!-- enter code here -->
</div>
```

**app.ts**

```
export class Test {
    Option = [
      { value: 'usd', name: 'america'},
      { value: 'cad', name: 'canada money'}
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Rajkumar you should really make some more effort trying to work this out. You do not even have the code for the basic select, the code for which is all over the internet, an example : https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/working-with-forms-in-aurelia/

That said I will try and help:

```
<template>
<form role="form">
    <select value.bind="selectedVal">
        <option repeat.for="option of someOptions"
             model.bind="option">${option.name}</option>
    </select>
</form>
</template>

<div class="row" show.bind="selectedVal === 'usd'">
  UsD SeLeCtEd
</div>

<div class="row" show.bind="selectedVal !== 'usd'">
  Other SeLeCtEd
</div>
```

The above should show only the "usd selected" content when you select USD, and "other selected" when you select anything else. This is not the best way of doing it but should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice !